# sqlite multiple writes at same time

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, python-requests, flask-sqlalchemy

i'm making a python flask app with sqlite database
is there a way to make a queue for write requests so that it can run smoothly AS SQLITE doesn't support multiple concurrent writes or commits

this is my connection string

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///IT_DataBase.db',
                       connect_args={'check_same_thread': False})
Base.metadata.bind = engine
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()
```

and this is the commit code as example:

```
@app.route('/NewRequest', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def NewRequest():
    connUser=session.query(User).filter(User.id==Session.get('user_id')).one()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        Types = session.query(Req_Type.id,Req_Type.Type_name)
        Pr = session.query(Req_Priorities.id,Req_Priorities.Priority_name)
        return render_template('NewRequest.html',conn=connUser ,name=current_user.name, items=Types,priorities=Pr)
    else:
        name= request.form['Name']
        Description= request.form['Description']
        Type = request.form.get('Type')
        Priority = request.form.get('Priority')
        newRequest = Requests(name=name, Record_Created=datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), Description=Description, Assigned_To=None, Type_Name=str(Type), Priority_Name=str(Priority), Status_Name='Opened', User_ID=Session.get('user_id') )
        session.add(newRequest)
        flash('New Request With Name %s Successfully Created' % newRequest.name)
        session.commit()
        UserRequests= session.query(Requests).filter_by(User_ID=Session.get('user_id')).filter(Requests.Status_Name!='Solved').all()
        return render_template('ReqData.html',conn=connUser , title='User Requests', rows=UserRequests)
```

i think that if we didn't change the database engine the solution is either to queue the commits but i don't know how
or to make flask wait random time before commiting but i think this will make performance poor
what should i do

Comment: connect to sqlite using WAL: https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html

Comment: still getting this error    "InvalidRequestError: This session is in 'prepared' state; no further SQL can be emitted within this transaction.
"

Comment: i decided to make commits happen only once in a while, i know it  seems like a bad i dea, but for now it's working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to serialize the commits. Create a lock like below.

```
from threading import RLock

sql_lock = RLock()
```

Wrap session.add and session.commit like the following. `lock.acquire()` will block the code while another thread has acquired the lock, and is yet to release the lock. This ensures that only one thread (or none) is running between `acquire()` and `release()` at all times.

```
    try:
        sql_lock.acquire()
        session.add(newRequest)
        session.commit()
    finally:
        sql_lock.release()
```

Comment: That is because you can't use the same session to make queries between `session.add(object)` and `session.commit()`. Once an object is added to a session, it is 'prepared' to be committed, and you cannot use it for queries until you commit it. In this case, it's the other threads trying to use the session to query. You can solve this by giving each thread its own session. Or if you feel lazy, you can put `session = DBSession()` at the top of NewRequest and other views that use SQLAlchemy. Try the lazy method first to confirm this is indeed the issue.

Comment: won't i using the lazy way be creating a session for each user connected to the app ? is this the better option or the threaded one ? how can we implement it ?

Comment: Yes, it does create a new session for every request. And that is how it is supposed to be. You cannot re-use sessions across different contexts anyways. So the "lazy" way is the better and safer way in general. Create a new session from the session maker with `session = DBSession()` every time you need to use a session. Like ```def NewRequest(): session = DBSession()```